# PHP implode not working with single quotes?

Tags: php, mysql, implode

I've searched for about the last hour regarding this issue, but its becoming quite annoying...

Anyways, I'm trying to insert data into a mysqli db, i've done this numerous times before but for some reason I cannot figure out what is going wrong...

```
<?php

require_once("../config/dbmetar.php");

$delimiter = ',';
$file = "metars.csv";
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST_METAR, DB_USER_METAR, DB_PASS_METAR, DB_NAME_METAR);
$r = 0;

if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {

    if ($r >= 6) {

        foreach($data as $i => $content) { 

            $data[$i] = $db->real_escape_string($content);

        }

        echo "INSERT INTO metars VALUES('" . implode("','", $data) . "');" . "<br>";
        //$db->query("INSERT INTO metars VALUES('" . implode("','", $data) . "');" );

    }

    $r++;

}

fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

The main issue is with the insert into metars values... the values should all be comma delimited with single quotes around each field value...

Currently this is what the echo is exporting:

```
INSERT INTO metars VALUES('PAJZ 011132Z AUTO 1 3/4SM BR FEW009 BKN019 OVC026 08/07 A2959 RMK AO2 PWINO TSNO P0001,PAJZ,2013-07-01T11:32:00Z,59.73,-157.27,8.0,7.0,,,,1.75,29.589567,,,TRUE,TRUE,,,TRUE,,TRUE,BR,FEW,900,BKN,1900,OVC,2600,,,IFR,,,,,,0.01,,,,,,SPECI,82.0');
```

Any suggestions?

Var_dump($data) returned these:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(238) "PAJZ 011132Z AUTO 1 3/4SM BR FEW009 BKN019 OVC026 08/07 A2959 RMK AO2 PWINO TSNO P0001,PAJZ,2013-07-01T11:32:00Z,59.73,-157.27,8.0,7.0,,,,1.75,29.589567,,,TRUE,TRUE,,,TRUE,,TRUE,BR,FEW,900,BKN,1900,OVC,2600,,,IFR,,,,,,0.01,,,,,,SPECI,82.0" } INSERT INTO metars VALUES('');
array(1) { [0]=> string(153) "CYOD 011131Z 18002KT 1/2SM FG FEW250 RMK CI0,CYOD,2013-07-01T11:31:00Z,54.4,-110.28,,,180,2,,0.5,,,,,,,,,,,FG,FEW,25000,,,,,,,LIFR,,,,,,,,,,,,SPECI,544.0" } INSERT INTO metars VALUES('');
array(1) { [0]=> string(276) "CYYD 011131Z AUTO VRB06KT 5SM -RA BR FEW007 BKN070 OVC084 15/14 A3005 RMK PRESRR PCPN 1.0MM PAST HR SLP173 DENSITY ALT 1900FT,CYYD,2013-07-01T11:31:00Z,54.82,-127.18,15.0,14.0,0,6,,5.0,30.050198,1017.3,,TRUE,,,,,,,-RA BR,FEW,700,BKN,7000,OVC,8400,,,MVFR,,,,,,,,,,,,SPECI,523.0" }
```

Comment: `var_dump($data)`, you're probably not actually getting an array of multiple values.

Comment: ...the reason for which is likely an encoding problem somewhere which means the delimiter doesn't match.

Comment: "the values should all be comma delimited with single quotes around each field value..." It appears that only strings are quoted in the input, while booleans, dates, and numbers are not.

Comment: @Powerlord Nothing *needs* to be quoted in CSV unless it contains the delimiter character.

Comment: @deceze Exactly, but the posted code assumes all lines are quoted.

Comment: @Powerlord Where does it assume that?

Comment: @deceze The implode statement's delimiter.

Comment: @Powerlord He's imploding into SQL syntax, in which each value must be quote delimited. It's irrelevant whether the CSV was quoted or not, that has already (*should have been already*) been parsed away by `fgetcsv`.

Answer (score 2):

This means $data has 1 item, because implode works just fine this way.

```
var_dump($data);
```

Please run the dump. Maybe you have wrong delimiter, so $data has one single element.

Comment: Did the var_dump... seems as if the array being built is a single string as you had mentioned... is there an easy way to correct it?

Comment: Seems delimiter is fine. Check your locale, php.net says it can affect the result.

Answer (score -1):

I try these codes :

```
$a = array('PAJZ 011132Z AUTO 1 3/4SM BR FEW009 BKN019 OVC026 08/07 A2959 RMK AO2 PWINO TSNO P0001','PAJZ', '2013-07-01T11:32:00Z','','a','b','');
```

echo implode("','", $a);

The result is :
 [image]

It works fine!

my php version is : 
PHP 5.3.19 (cli) (built: Apr 30 2013 21:16:28) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

and you can find this in php.net[image: http://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.implode.php]

So, check your php version !

Comment: PHP Version 5.4.16, I see how you got that results, but then I have to ask why is my foreach loop not working as intended?